# Get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch for some but not all attempts to change JSON attribute value

Tags: java, json, groovy, linkedhashmap, jsonslurper

IDE: IntelliJ IdEA 2017.2.4 Language: Groovy 2.4.11 Test Framework: Spock 1.1-groovy-2.4

New to all of the above. No prior experience in Java either.  First post here and I actually read the intro and guidelines and trying my best to follow.

JSON request:

```
{
  "source": "source",
  "quoteId": null,
  "quoteVersion": null,
  "quote": {
    "globalTransactionId": "k2o4-6969-1fie-poef",
    "quoteStatus": "Not Uploaded",
    "events": {
      "eventDescription": "event description",
      "eventTypeName": "Event Type"
    },
    "someReport": {
      "acceptResultsFlag": "Y",
      "orderDate": "2017-06-14",
      "orderStatus": "string"
    },
    "anotherReport": {
      "id": 627311,
      "orderDate": "2017-06-14"
    },
    "attributes": [
      {
        "appliedFlag": "Y",
        "attributeDetail": {
          "name": "attribute1",
          "value": "value1"
        },
        "attributeName": "attribute1"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

When I attempt to change quote.attributes.appliedFlag I get:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch at com.serviceSpecIdeaNo2.NULL values: verify response codes and message content.(serviceSpecIdeaNo2.groovy:23)

Code:

```
class serviceSpecIdeaNo2 extends Specification {

    def 'NULL values: verify response codes and message content.'() {

        given: 'a JSON request with null field values'
        def url = 'http://someservice.com:1234'
        def path = '/endPoint'
        def client = new RESTClient(url)
        client.handler.failure = client.handler.success

        def inputFile  = new File('input.json')
        def json = new JsonSlurper().parse(inputFile)

        def changeValueTo = null

        def (lvl1, lvl2, lvl3, lvl4, lvl5) = data.fullPath.tokenize('.')

        if (lvl5 != null) {
            json."$lvl1"."$lvl2"."$lvl3"."$lvl4"."$lvl5" = changeValueTo
        } else if (lvl4 != null) {
            json."$lvl1"."$lvl2"."$lvl3"."$lvl4" = changeValueTo
        } else if (lvl3 != null) {
            json."$lvl1"."$lvl2"."$lvl3" = changeValueTo
        } else if (lvl2 != null) {
            json."$lvl1"."$lvl2" = changeValueTo
        } else {
            json."$lvl1" = changeValueTo
        }

        when: 'the request is submitted'
        def response = client.post([
                path              : path,
                requestContentType: JSON,
                body              : json
        ])
```

Stacktrace

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
DUMMY.groovy: 1: unexpected token: DUMMY @ line 1, column 30.
   java.util.LinkedHashMapclass DUMMY { public groovy.lang.Closure _JETGROOVY_EVAL_ = {json->((java.util.LinkedHashMap)json).entrySet().toArray()[2]}}
                                ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:254)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:211)
    at com.serviceSpecIdeaNo2.$spock_feature_0_0(serviceSpecIdeaNo2.groovy:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:188)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:481)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:464)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeatureMethod(BaseSpecRunner.java:406)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:324)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$6.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:309)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:481)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:464)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:288)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.initializeAndRunIteration(BaseSpecRunner.java:278)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.ParameterizedSpecRunner.runIterations(ParameterizedSpecRunner.java:139)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.ParameterizedSpecRunner.runParameterizedFeature(ParameterizedSpecRunner.java:41)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:262)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$5.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:246)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:481)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:464)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeature(BaseSpecRunner.java:238)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runFeatures(BaseSpecRunner.java:188)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.doRunSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:98)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner$1.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invokeRaw(BaseSpecRunner.java:481)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.invoke(BaseSpecRunner.java:464)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.runSpec(BaseSpecRunner.java:76)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.BaseSpecRunner.run(BaseSpecRunner.java:67)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik.run(Sputnik.java:63)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch

    at com.qa.ServiceSpecIdeaNo2.NULL values: verify response codes and message content.(serviceSpecIdeaNo2.groovy:23)
```

Comment: Besides that `json."$lvl1"."$lvl2"."$lvl3"."$lvl4"."$lvl4"` should probably be `json."$lvl1"."$lvl2"."$lvl3"."$lvl4"."$lvl5"`, where do you get the error? You should post the full stack trace of your error. Except that was already the problem, then tell me and I make it an answer for you to accept.

Comment: Typo in transferring. Thank you.

Comment: I added the stack trace.  Also updated the JSON example to include a field/attribute like the one it's failing on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really improve your question it is very low quality. It has many typos and errors.

After I changed a few things I was able to reproduce your error. But as you had many other things wrong I'm not 100% sure it is the same you got. In my case the problem is, that in your JSON you have

```
"attribute": [
  {
    "appliedFlag": "Y",
    "attributeDetail": {
      "name": "attra",
      "value": "value1"
    },
    "attributeName": "attra"
  }
]
```

This means `attribute` is a list. So if you query `record.attribute.appliedFlag`, you get a list of all the appliedFlag attributes of the entries in the list and thus you get the error when you try to set it.